# MYSQL Attempting to update table1.grp_dir with a group_concat from table1.dir

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have tried two ways.  One, just referencing back to itself for a subselect, then I tried creating a temp table, loading the needed data and then subselecting off of that temp table.  Neither has worked.

```
UPDATE t_call_details cd,
(SELECT 
    sessionid,
        GROUP_CONCAT(dir
            ORDER BY call_start
            SEPARATOR '|') AS gc_dir
FROM
    t_call_details
GROUP BY sessionid) AS gc 
SET 
cd.overall_calldirection = gc.gc_dir
WHERE
cd.sessionid = gc.sessionid
    AND ISNULL(cd.overall_calldirection)
```

Next I tried...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_t_call_details LIKE t_call_details;

INSERT INTO temp_t_call_details (id, sessionid, dir) SELECT id, sessionid, dir from t_call_details where isnull(t_call_details.overall_calldirection);

UPDATE t_call_details cd,
(SELECT 
    sessionid,
        GROUP_CONCAT(dir
            ORDER BY call_start
            SEPARATOR '|') AS gc_dir
FROM
    temp_t_call_details
GROUP BY sessionid) AS gc 
SET 
cd.overall_calldirection = gc.gc_dir
WHERE
cd.sessionid = gc.sessionid
    AND cd.year = 2018
    AND ISNULL(cd.overall_calldirection);
```

I just receive Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query at just over 600 sec each time.  I think my code is accurate; it should work.  Is there a timeout I am missing that I need to update to a larger number?

Comment: I'm afraid, that sub-query without a `where` clause executes for an entire table at each single update. You need a `where` clause in it.

Comment: I suspect this error occurs when running the query in MySQL workbench; that is, the timeout is occurring on MySQL workbench, not on MySQL server.

Comment: @spencer7593, that was my suspicion as well, but I'm not familiar enough with MySQL WB to know where to look for the timeout... any thoughts?  It's 6.3.

Comment: @revo indeed; Originally I had a 'where isnull(t_call_details.overall_calldirection)' but had removed that while testing.